# Audio Reactivity Is Too Jittery

Tags: audio, emission

I'm working on this project for a client where the emission strength of the lights within a sci-fi city react to his tracks. I've baked sound to f-curves but the change in emission is way too jittery, so I've read that the way to possibly fix this is to have the emission react to frequencies rather than the overall volume levels of the track. I want the lights to react to the kick drum rather than everything, or at least have the animation be a bit smoother. But I'm not too familiar with this and cant find much about how it works especially in blender.

It would be awesome if someone could shed some light on this and/or direct me to a tutorial or guide to sorting this out! I can provide test files and video files if need be! Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

For smooth the baked sound you can go on Graph Editor to menu Key > Un-bake Curve, this create keyframes for the curve, then in menu Key > Smooth key for smooth the keyframes of the curve, also you can press Alt + O for do that.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps! Do you also possibly know a way i can have it rather than smooth but on and off, as such with emission? So having the sound cause it to react as an on off switch so the emission goes from 0 to whatever i set the max as?

Comment: Yes, you can use the limits Modificator, with selected curve on right panel of Graph Editor, you can see the modifiers panel. For better effect you can scale up the curve on Y axis then move the curve below zero, then set the limits from 0 to whatever you need. [Screenshoot](https://imgur.com/a/xn3pVJD)

Comment: I cannot unbake my f-curve, is this because it's an emission key frame? when i select the key frame / curve it doesn't give me the option to unbake.

Comment: If you can share your project, I can review the problem